# Where does a line cross my curve?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have a starting point **(X,Y)** and a starting direction **(V1,V2)**. Also I have two specific curves

```
g1: 2*x - (y)^2 - 1 = 0;
g2: 9 - 0.8*(x)^2 - 2*y = 0;
```

I need to know where will the first intersection occur given any **(X,Y)** and **(V1,V2)** (or if it doesn't occur at all within some fixed **R** distance).

What is the simplest way to do it? What standard MatLab methods should I consider?

---

For example **(X,Y)=(0,0)** and **(V1,V2)=(1,1)**. The first intersection occurs at **(1,1)** and it is a point of **g1** curve.

[image: intersection]

Comment: So are you saying your cruves are found taking a slice out of each surface (g1, g2) in the (V1, V2) direction?

Comment: @Dan g1 and g2 are simple curves on a plane. I corrected my post. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Have you already tried with the `symbolic` toolbox? or do you prefer a `numerical` solution?

Comment: @fpe I have pretty much no experience with symbolic work using MatLab. I need whatever that in the end gives numerical approximation of intersection coordinates.

Comment: @Pranasas: so, you are not interested in curves roots at all!

Comment: @fpe Well it depends. I am interested in a half-line (ray) intersecting fixed given curves.

Comment: OK I see, so use my solution but make a third line, g3 that's just a straight line with (V1, V2) specifying the gradient. Check where it intersect both g1 and g2, and pick the closer value

Comment: @Pranasas See the latest edit on my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the intersection of two curves:

Declare g1 and g2 as explicit anonymous functions

```
g1 = @(x)(sqrt(2*x - 1));
g2 = @(x)(-0.4*x.^2 + 4.5);
```

Choose a range for x to test over:

```
xmin = 0;
xmax = 100;
xres = 0.1;
x = xmin:xres:xmax;
```

Find in the curves

```
G1 = g1(x);
G2 = g2(x);
```

Now find the index where the graphs cross each other:

```
ind = find(diff(G1 > G2));
```

Now it's easy to convert that index to an `x` value:

```
xval = xmin + (ind(1)-1)*xres
```

**EDIT:**

So I'm assuming now that your (V1,V2) is just a unit direction vector from the origin? If so we can create a straight line y = mx+c and find where that intersect g1 and g2.

```
m = V2/V1;
c = Y - m*X;
line = @(x)(m*x + c);
```

now just follow the procedure above to find the point of intersection of `line` and `g1` and also of `line` and `g2`. If V1 is negative, then set `xmax = X` otherwise set `xmin = X` so that you look for the intersection point in the right direction. The `xval` line will probably error if there is no point of intersection so add some error checking in there. And then just pick the smallest xval if V1 was positive or the larger if V1 is negative

```
if V1 >= 0
    xmin = X;
    xmax = X + 100;
else
    xmin = X - 100;
    xmax = X; 
end;

xres = 0.1;
x = xmin:xres:xmax;

G1 = g1(x);
G2 = g2(x);
L = line(x);
ind1 = find(diff(G1 > L));
xval1 = xmin + (ind1(1)-1)*xres
ind2 = find(diff(G2 > L));
xval2 = xmin + (ind2(1)-1)*xres

xval = (V1 > 0)*max(xval1, xval2) + (V2 < 0)*max(xval1, xval2);
yval = line(xval);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you just wanted to give me a hint since g1 and g2 are always the same. It's the starting point and starting direction that is arbitrary. This effectively introduces a third curve (a line) which has to be taken care of. Well I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by starting direction, you have provided two explicit curves. Starting point I understand (just change `xmin` in the code above) but what do you mean by direction? You can either be increasing `x` or decreasing `x`? oh unless I halved the curve by taking sqrt...

Comment: So my method gives `x` = 2.5 for +ve root and `x` = 4.2 for the -ve root. So I guess that's where your direction comes into play.

Comment: Imagine an object living in a 2D space and currently located at **(X,Y)**. Object starts moving in a given direction **(V1,V2)**. It will hopefully cross/touch one of a fixed curves g1 or g2. That is the coordinates I'm interested in.

Comment: @Dan: your resolution is correct as well: you approach the problem from a geometrical view, which is quite elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way, but I cannot currently test it:

**EDIT 3**

Now I should have interpreted the question in the right way: so I would proceed this way:

```
f1 = @(x) x - (sqrt( 2.*x - 1 ));
f2 = @(x) x - (4.5 - 0.4.*(x).^2);
x1 = fsolve(f1,x01)
x2 = fsolve(f2,x02)
```

This should lead you to the expected results:

```
x1 = 1;
x2 = 2.3295;
```

Or, alternatively, you may follow the symbolic approach:

```
syms x;
x1 = double(solve(x - sqrt(2*x - 1)));
x2 = double(solve(x - (4.5 - 0.4*x^2)));
```

Comment: I added a picture to my original post in order to represent (hopefully in a clearer manner) the intersection I am actually interested in.

Comment: @Pranasas: I just updated the answer; check if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
% find intersect point of two curves
% x -> independent variable
% y1, y2 -> curves that intersects
% xc, yc -> intersect cordinate

function [xc, yc, crossIdx] = findIntersectPoint(x, y1, y2)
    crossIdx = inf;
    xRes = (x(end) - x(1))/(length(x) - 1);
    for xVal = x(1):xRes:x(end)
        idx = fix((xVal - x(1)) / xRes + 2);
        if ( (y1(idx-1) <= y2(idx-1)) && (y1(idx) >= y2(idx)) )  
            crossIdx = idx;
            break;
        end
    end
    if(crossIdx ~= inf)
        xc = x(crossIdx);
        yc = y1(crossIdx);
    else
        xc = nan;
        yc = nan;
    end
end
```